# change speed of transition in scrolling sideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow, transition

I found some code for a scrolling slideshow which I want to use and I figured out how to alter the duration of each slide as it comes to rest, but not how to change the duration of the actual transition (the part where the slide moves in and out.  I have pasted the code here.  Can someone tell me where in the js I need to change values?  Also, can this same effect be achieved using just css, and if so, can someone explain how?  Ideally I would like to use just css since I think it would be simpler and I am more familiar with it.  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-left" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/23rd_st.jpg" alt="Mountain" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-left" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/blue.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-left" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/broken_guru.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-left" src="https://www.bartonlewis.com/_imagesfilm/church_ave.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>  

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2500);    
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the actual fade/slide in transition effect is already being handled by CSS animations, via this style:

```
.w3-animate-left {
    position: relative;
    animation: animateleft 0.4s;
}
```

If you duplicate that style locally you should be able to override it and increase the duration, e.g. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrJeoB

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript you need need to change,
`setTimeout(carousel, 2500);`

This Javascript function is actually Calling `carousel`
function every `2500` that is 2.5 Seconds.

you can increase/decrease your 2500 values which is 2.5 Seconds  as you like .
And  for 1 Seconds you need to change the value  to 1000 .

and for css
you can USE . `transition delay 2s`

Comment: As I noted in my answer, the style is currently using CSS animation - be wary of adding CSS transition to it as well (you can of course use transition to achieve the same effect, but you'll probably want to override the existing animation styles so you don't have two effects occurring on the same element at the same time - bad for performance and likely to look odd).

Comment: Thank you.  It wasn't clear to me what was responsible for the effects - js or css - since the code I copied contained js.  What is the js doing here?  There are other things I'd like to tweak such as the opacity on the transition, which I don't like.  Since the css is not shown as it's in a stylesheet and when I access that link it's just a page of code that's not in any kind of readable fashion, I don't know how to access or edit the css.  Can you tell me how I can access the css so that I can modify it?  Many thanks, Barton